# how to update all objects within an array that has matching values?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a couple of inserts for a collection:

```
db.customerOrder.insert (
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderNumber": "ord003",
      "orderDate": ISODate("2020-01-10T00:00:00Z"),
      "staffNumber": "stf789",
    },
    {
      "orderNumber": "ord005",
      "orderDate": ISODate("2020-03-17T00:00:00Z"),
      "staffNumber": "stf444",
    },
    {
      "orderNumber": "ord005",
      "orderDate": ISODate("2020-02-22T00:00:00Z"),
      "staffNumber": "stf890",
    }
  ]
}
);

db.customerOrder.insert (
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderNumber": "ord001",
      "orderDate": ISODate("2020-04-23T00:00:00Z"),
      "staffNumber": "stf123",
    },
    {
      "orderNumber": "ord005",
      "orderDate": ISODate("2020-04-16T00:00:00Z"),
      "staffNumber": "stf444",
    }
  ]
}
);

db.customerOrder.insert (
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderNumber": "ord001",
      "orderDate": ISODate("2020-02-10T00:00:00Z"),
      "staffNumber": "stf123",
    },
    {
      "orderNumber": "ord005",
      "orderDate": ISODate("2020-04-10T00:00:00Z"),
      "staffNumber": "stf890",
    }
  ]
}
);

db.customerOrder.insert (
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "orderNumber": "ord005",
      "orderDate": ISODate("2020-05-15T00:00:00Z"),
      "staffNumber": "stf123",
    },
    {
      "orderNumber": "ord004",
      "orderDate": ISODate("2020-02-25T00:00:00Z"),
      "staffNumber": "stf890",
    }
  ]
}
);
```

These were inserted through a terminal, I am not using any server sided language like php and etc, just data manipulation using the terminal.

May I know how I can change the stfNumber to stf100 for all orderNumber with ord005?

I have tried this

```
db.customerOrder.update({"orders.orderNumber":"ord005"},{"$set":{"orders.$.staffNumber":"stf100"}})
```

Unfornately, only the first object with ord005 is updated with the staffNumber to stf100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [filtered-Positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) array update operator

your query may look something like this

```
db.customerOrder.updateMany(
    { "orders.orderNumber": "ord005" }, // filter part
    { "$set": { "orders.$[order].staffNumber": "stf100" } }, // update part
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'order.orderNumber': 'ord005' }] } // options part, to define which orders will be updated according to some condition
)
```

hope it helps

Comment: it only updates all occurrences in the first document :(

Comment: okay, I have updated my answer, we need to use `updateMany` instead of `update`, I tested it in mongo shell, and it's working as expected, could you check it again?